# Is cross multiplication the right term?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I always hear the term **cross multiplication** when it comes to equations with fractions such as $$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{a}{b}$$ where the cross multiplication is the act of multiplying $b$ and $x$, and $a$ and $y$ to get $$bx = ay.$$ What I don't get is the existence of the term at all. Isn't this just multiplication at all? This term might even get confused with the **cross product**.

---

What is the reason why cross multiplication exists even though it is just multiplication?

Comment: Ok, sorry, but I had a laugh reading this question

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say yourself "cross multiplication is **the act of** multiplying $b$ and $x$, and $a$ and $y$".

Of course, mathematically, it is "just multiplication". But humans, and in particular young students, think of operations "procedurally". The idea is to let them see the approach ("do *this*"), not the formal operation ("just multiplication").

[On a similar note, to students the statements $$2 \cdot 3=6$$
and $$6= 2\cdot 3$$ are *not the same*: They would say that the first is a multiplication, the second is factoring. And there is something to say in favour of this, on the meta-level, even though "mathematically" the two statements are completely equivalent. But a human mind does not think of a statement as only a statement, rather it naturally interprets it as part of a task, a solution to a certain problem.]

Or to put it in yet other words: Mathematically, "cross multiplication" is just a redundant term for multiplication. Pedagogically, it shows students a specific approach to a specific kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

Cross multiplication is an informal name for the problem-solving technique, not a word with a technical definition referring to a mathematical object.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect $x$ with $b$ with a line, and then $a$ with $y$ with another line (i.e. if you connect the terms you multiply) they form a cross. That's why it's called this way.

I doubt you can confuse this with cross product because one is studied in 6th or 7th grade, the other one in university.

Comment: I get that they form a cross. What I don't get is the existence of the term itself. It is just multiplication, why make a term just for fractions?

Comment: Simple: to teach the kids in a more visual way, to make them easily remember the rule.

Comment: It’s simply a way to test the equality of two fractions, nothing more and nothing mysterious.